# How to make Highcharts Tilemap to fill the whole space?

Tags: highcharts

Since Highcharts tilemap with hexagon shape does not guarantee to render regular hexagons, I am computing the size of the chart by myself to get the regular hexagons based on the hexagon layout:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'tilemap',
        height: 200, //result of computation, could be any number
        width: 200 //result of computation, could be any number
    }
```

The problem is that even if I set the correct size of the chart wrapper, the hexagons in the tilemap do not fill the whole content.

Here is the fiddle with extreme case of 1 single hexagon (but it is happening for all kinds of layouts, sometimes more, sometimes less).

http://jsfiddle.net/auqp1jw2/1/

I such case, I would expect the hexagon to fill the whole 200x200 area, but it only covers 85pixels.

Comment: What is the final output that you want to achieve? Maybe it will be easier to achieve by using the polygon series: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polygon

Comment: The desired state is to have a container with regular hexagons in honeycomb layout in multiple clusters. The problem is that the number of hexagons and the layout is computed on the backend and the honeycomb layout is also affected by the aspect ratio of the container (I want the layout to be responsive). Another problem (and it is the major one) is that the shape of the hexagon depends on the container size and I am trying to calculate the container size to make the hexagons regular

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I think the only approach is this suggested by the Highcharts core developer that you can find in this discussion - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10200